# How to print leaves of a tree implemented as a list of subtrees in Python?

Tags: python, list, tree

Basically I want to be able to have each node of type tree have a Data field and a list of branches. This list should contain a number of objects of type Tree.
I think I have the actual implementation of the list down, but I get strange behavior when I try using the getLeaves method. Basically it calls itself recursively and never returns, and the way that happens is somehow the second node of the tree gets it's first branch set as itself (I think).

```
class Tree:
    """Basic tree graph datatype"""
    branches = []

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def addBranch (self, addition):
    """Adds another object of type Tree as a branch"""
        self.branches += [addition]

    def getLeaves (self):
        """returns the leaves of a given branch. For leaves of the tree, specify root"""
        print (len(self.branches))
        if (len(self.branches) == 0):
            return self.root
        else:
            branchSum = []
            for b in self.branches:
                branchSum += b.getLeaves()
            return (branchSum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'branches' variable is a class member, not an instance member. You need to initialize the 'branches' instance variable in the constructor:

```
class Tree:
    """Basic tree graph datatype"""

    def __init__(self, root):
       self.branches = []
       self.root = root
```

The rest of your code looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Is `self.root` the parent of said tree?  In that case, `getLeaves()` should return `self` if it has no branches (`len(self.branches)==0`) instead of `self.root` as you have it there. Also, if you do have child branches you should include `self` within `branchSum`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution (your source code with small changes):

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, data):
        """Basic tree graph datatype"""
        self.data = data
        self.branches = []

    def addBranch (self, addition):
        """Adds another object of type Tree as a branch"""
        self.branches.append(addition)

    def getLeaves (self):
        """returns the leaves of a given branch. For 
           leaves of the tree, specify data"""
        if len(self.branches) == 0:
            return self.data
        else:
            branchSum = []
            for b in self.branches:
                branchSum.append(b.getLeaves())
            return branchSum

## Use it

t0 = Tree("t0")
t1 = Tree("t1")
t2 = Tree("t2")
t3 = Tree("t3")
t4 = Tree("t4")

t0.addBranch(t1)
t0.addBranch(t4)
t1.addBranch(t2)
t1.addBranch(t3)

print(t0.getLeaves())
```

Output:

```
[['t2', 't3'], 't4']
```

Remarks:

1. Looks that some formatting is broken in your code.
2. Not really sure if this is what you want. Do you want all the leaves in one level of the list? (If so the source code has to be adapted.)